# Mongodb get count of unique values

Tags: java, mongodb

I have data collection like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a42914eef0ba24b49cbf3a"),
    "user" : "111",
    "contact" : "555"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a42922eef0ba24b49cbf3b"),
    "user" : "111",
    "contact" : "666"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a4292deef0ba24b49cbf3c"),
    "user" : "111",
    "contact" : "666"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a42934eef0ba24b49cbf3d"),
    "user" : "222",
    "contact" : "666"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a42938eef0ba24b49cbf3e"),
    "user" : "222",
    "contact" : "777"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a4293eeef0ba24b49cbf3f"),
    "user" : "222",
    "contact" : "888"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a4293feef0ba24b49cbf40"),
    "user" : "222",
    "contact" : "888"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a42941eef0ba24b49cbf41"),
    "user" : "222",
    "contact" : "888"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a42947eef0ba24b49cbf42"),
    "user" : "333",
    "contact" : "888"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a4294ceef0ba24b49cbf43"),
    "user" : "333",
    "contact" : "666"
},
```

Can I get result listing contacts in each user along with their count, like this in Java?

```
{user:user_name,data[contact:count]}
```

So the result should be like follows, each user has a list of contact with their count

```
{user:111,contact:[{555:1},{666:2}]},{user:222,contact:[{666:1},{777:1},{888:3}]},{user:333,contact:[{888:1},{666:1}]}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried many things, last try was this db.data.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: { user
    : "$user" },   // replace `name` here twice
    uniqueIds: { $addToSet: {"contact":{_id:"$contact",count: {$sum: 1}}} },
    count: { $sum: 1 } 
  } }, 
  { $match: { 
    count: { $gte: 2 } 
  } },
  { $sort : { count : -1} },
  { $limit : 10 }
]);

Comment: it is near to what i want but not exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the idea is `$group` couple of times, first calculate count while grouping on `user` and `contact` and the other grouping on `user` to push the `contact` and `count`. I've included the areas of query that needed change

```
db.data.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            user: "$user",
            contact: "$contact"
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.user",
        uniqueIds: {
            $push: {
                contact: "$_id.contact",
                count: "$count"
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

You cant get the response the way you wanted. You'll always have key and value pair.

Sample Response:

```
{
    "_id": "111",
    "uniqueIds": [{
        "contact": "555",
        "count": 1
    }, {
        "contact": "666",
        "count": 2
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Veeram, you are a star!